# how to use url parameters in html?

Tags: javascript, html, url, web

I get URL parameters using Javascript but i can't use those variables in my html.
the JS code is this:

```
<script>
var url_string = window.location.href; //window.location.href
var url = new URL(url_string);
var c = url.searchParams.get("name");
console.log(c);
</script>
```

and my URL is `localhost:8000/something?name=ABC`.here i can get the value of name and show it in the browser console but when i try to set the value of an input tag in my HTML it doesn't do it and raises some errors.
my JS and html is like:

```
<script>
    var url_string = window.location.href; //window.location.href
    var url = new URL(url_string);
    var c = url.searchParams.get("name");
    document.getElementById("user").value =url.searchParams.get("name");
    </script>
<input id="user" value"">
```

this should have changed the value of the input tag but doesn't.

Comment: *'it doesn't do it and raises some errors'* - Please provide the error messages.

Comment: html is a markup language and has no access to url params, research php and `$_GET` - probs can do something with JS but is not my area of expertise

Answer (score 5):

if your #user input is call before the DOM content is loaded,

```
document.getElementById("user").value
```

javascript can't find it so he try to set "value" of an undefined element

try this :

```
<input id="user" value="">    
<script>
    var url_string = window.location.href; //window.location.href
    var url = new URL(url_string);
    var c = url.searchParams.get("name");
    document.getElementById("user").value = c;
</script>
```

Comment: it worked :)),thanks

Comment: @Parsa mark as correct ^^ :)

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one URL parameter this will work. Just make sure that your input element is defined first.

A working copy [JsFiddle static input](https://jsfiddle.net/nhc1238g/)

**HTML**

```
<input id="user" value="">
```

**JS**

```
var url = "localhost:8000/something?name=ABC" //replace with code to get url
var name = url.substring(url.indexOf("=") + 1);  
document.getElementById("user").value = name;
```

If you need the input element to be defined after you get the URL parameter:

A working copy [JsFiddle dynamic input](https://jsfiddle.net/67hntLxr/5/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="myDiv"> </div>
```

**JS**

```
var url = "localhost:8000/something?name=ABC" //replace with code to get url
var name = url.substring(url.indexOf("=") + 1);  

var parent = document.getElementById("myDiv");
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.value = name;
parent.appendChild(input)
```